# imagemagick draw text word wrapping

Tags: script, imagemagick

I have this script, which writes text to images.

```
echo \\n"List? {y/n}"
read cont
if
[ "$cont" = "y" ] || [ "$cont" = "Y" ]
then
rm -rf sponsors.txt

    ls *.jpg *.png *.gif -1 > sponsors2.txt
    while read line
do
echo " >$line" >> sponsors.txt
done < sponsors2.txt
fi

read -p "$pause" "Press [Enter] key to start..."

while IFS='>' read field1 field2 ; do
convert -pointsize 18 -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf -fill white -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -draw "text 1, 35 '$field1'" $field2 done/$field2
done < sponsors.txt

rm -rf sponsors2.txt
```

Prblem is word wrapping. Some of the lines are too long. I know convert is problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Caption option in the ImageMagick docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption). It explains how to do word wrapping.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, this works.